# Tool to assess volatile dependencies in codebase for IoC refactoring

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I'm attempting to refactor a large codebase to use StructureMap. Does anyone know if there's a tool to quickly scan a codebase and report the number of [*volatile* dependencies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/08/24/718828.aspx) within classes? Sure, I could always search all files for the word "new", but this would also find *non-volatile* dependencies such as those used from BCL which are not material. I suppose that NDepend could, *indirectly*, provide some report on the degree of coupling which, is, indirectly, what I'm looking to eliminate. I'm just wondering if there was some tool that was specifically designed for the purpose of assisting with the migration towards the use of an  IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything like that.  I think it would be quite hard to write a tool to identify volatile dependencies since they could be as diverse as file IO calls to database calls.  Also, many developers draw the line between volatile and not in different places.  Some would say System.Configuration is volatile, others would argue it is not...